# Jenkins - stop job running with a different user

Tags: jenkins

We have a Freestyle job which invokes a shell command to run some process with a different user:

```
sudo -u username my_prog
```

Now, we want Jenkins users to be able stop "my_prog" by clicking on a RED X button on the right on the build bar.
Is it possible? Can I catch this click event and run some script to kill the "my_prog"?

Answer (score 1):

You can kill/abort a job on Jenkins started by someone else. The **abort** initiator username will be captured in the console log.

You can disable this kill switch for everyone (including anonymous) by creating credentials for designated users(who can do both write and read action). For rest of the users , only read access shall be provisioned.

Comment: thanks but this is NOT what I'm asking. My problem is that the process is running on the agent under "username" is not killed when the job is stopped.

Comment: Jenkins is like a gun. Once a command has been fired , it will do its assigned task. My point on killing/aborting the job in progress implies that further command processing (from jenkins) shall be put on halt and build will be marked as "ABORTED". Since your command "sudo -u username my_prog" is delegating a super user task , execution will be triggered and handed over to system kernel. There is nothing (except restart) that can stop the kernel from doing its ordered task.